# Can constrained templated conversion operator kick in overload resolution of builtin operator?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts, overload-resolution

For [example](https://godbolt.org/z/ac7jcvrKG):

```cpp
#include <concepts>

struct A {
    int v;
    template<std::same_as<int> T>
    operator T() {return v;}
};
static_assert(std::same_as<int, decltype(A{4} + 2)>);

struct B {
    long long v;
    template<std::same_as<long long> T>
    operator T() {return v;}
};
static_assert(std::same_as<long long, decltype(B{4} + 2)>); //note that 2 is a int
```

Clang accepts both cases. GCC and MSVC reject both cases.
I guess it might be a bug of Clang, at least in the second case.

Who is correct in each case and how does the standard say?

Comment: `B` uses [`long long operator+(long long, int)`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over#built-12)

Comment: @Artyer oh thanks I see. So the compile have to iterator all builtin operators, e.g. for every pair of all builtin types, to see if there's one satisified conversion.